# Inquiry about the strongly convex and conjugate function

Tags: optimization

The easy statement tells me that the conjugate of a strongly convex function has a lipschitz continuous gradient.

But I am thinking about the how could a conjugate of a function is strongly convex. I cannot figure this out.

For example.

For the optimization, min $H(x)+G(y)$ such that $Ax+By=b$. Then the Lagrange function is $L(x,y,\lambda)=H(x)+G(y)-\lambda^{T}(Ax+By-b)$. According to the duality of original problem could be $D(\lambda)=-H^{*}(A^{T}\lambda)-G^{*}(B^{T}\lambda)+\langle\lambda,b\rangle$. Here, $H$ and $G$ are all strongly convex. And $G$ is quadratic, $B$ has full row rank.
Then could $-D$ is strongly convex?

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking "What conditions on $f$ guarantee that its conjugate $f^*$ is strongly convex?"

Comment: Yes, I cannot image an example. And a book gives a example that I mentioned in the question. I couldn't understand this example.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 14.2, Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space, let $f\colon\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and convex, and let $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$. The following are equivalent:

\begin{equation}
f^*\text{ is }\gamma^{-1}\text{ strongly convex}
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac{\gamma}{2}\|x\|^2 - f(x) \text{ is convex}.
\end{equation}

So it suffices to check if there exsits some constant such that the righthand side above is still convex.

A simple example is $f=\|\cdot\|^2$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful answer. I will check it